# free-jqgrid editing a column with edittype: "checkbox", editoptions.value: "1:0" doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

In **free-jqgrid**, when editing a column with *edittype: "checkbox"* and *editoptions.value = "1:0"*, it is impossible to set the field value to 1 if it was previously 0. When you check the field and submit the form, the column remains unchecked.

This worked well in **jqGrid**.

This strange behavior can be seen in the following [JSFiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/R_Caruso/dvyo36hw/) ( forked from an [OlegK's example](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/e6hu02z4/) )

In this example, if you edit and check the *inCharge* field of a previously unchecked field, after submitting the form, it remains unchecked.
On the other hand, if it was checked, you can either check or uncheck it, and after submitting, it will be as expected.
Moreover, when you add a record, if you check the *inCharge* field, it remains unchecked after submitting.

Here is the code

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";
  $("#grid").jqGrid({
      colModel: [{
          name: "id",
          width: 20,
          hidden: true,
          editable: false,
        },
        {
          name: "firstName",
          width: 200,
          editable: true
        },
        {
          name: "lastName",
          width: 200,
          editable: true
        },
        {
          name: "inCharge",
          width: 100,
          editable: true,
          formatter: "checkbox",
          edittype: "checkbox",
          editoptions: {
            value: "1:0"  // doesn't seem to work properly.
          }
        }
      ],
      data: [{
          id: 10,
          firstName: "Angela",
          lastName: "Merkel",
          inCharge: "1"
        },
        {
          id: 20,
          firstName: "Vladimir",
          lastName: "Putin",
          inCharge: "1"

        },
        {
          id: 30,
          firstName: "David",
          lastName: "Cameron",
          inCharge: "1"

        },
        {
          id: 40,
          firstName: "Barack",
          lastName: "Obama",
          inCharge: "0"

        },
        {
          id: 50,
          firstName: "François",
          lastName: "Hollande",
          inCharge: "0"

        }
      ],
      pager: true,
      pgbuttons: false,
      pginput: false,
      viewrecords: true,
      pagerRightWidth: 90
    })
    .jqGrid('navGrid', {
      edittext: 'Edit',
      addtext: 'Add',
      deltext: 'Del',
      search: false,
      view: true,
      viewtext: 'View',
      refresh: true,
      refreshtext: 'Refresh'
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.4/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.4/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
<table id="grid"></table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, which you describe is a bug in form editing, described in [the issue #432](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/432). The problem is already fixed in the code on the Git. The demo

```
https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/dvyo36hw/11/
```

uses your original code, but

```
https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js
```

instead of

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.4/jquery.jqgrid.min.js
```

One can verify that the problem is fixed.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg. By the way, when do you estimate that you will close 4.15.5 version and upload it to cdnjs ?

Comment: @RomualdoCaruso: You are welcome! I plan of cause to publish the latest code as new release, but I'm currently in the business trip and have a lot of other things to do. I'll still try to publish new version as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks again ! By the way, is there a way to show the checkboxes in the column not so dimmed ?

Comment: @RomualdoCaruso: You should just use Font Awesome 4.x. See [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#type_of_data)

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much !